# How to generate thumb image for 1 second video in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, thumbnails, avasset

I am not able to generate thumbnail for 1 second video. I have tried below code but it generates black image every time. I have tried passing timescale as (0,30), (0,1). It is working if video is above 1.5 seconds.

```
static func thumbnailFromVideo(videoUrl: URL, time: CMTime) -> UIImage {
    let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl) as AVAsset
    let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    do {
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
        let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return uiImage
    } catch {
        
    }
    return UIImage()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a frame accurate thumbnail you need to set the requested time tolerance before and after to zero:

From the docs:

> Set the values of requestedTimeToleranceBefore and requestedTimeToleranceAfter to zero to request frame-accurate image generation; this may incur additional decoding delay.

---

```
imgGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = .zero
imgGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = .zero
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is working for me.**

```
    func getvideosnapshot(url : URL , completion : @escaping ((UIImage?) ->())){
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let asset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let timestamp = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 600)
        do {
            let thumbnail = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: timestamp, actualTime: nil)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(UIImage(cgImage: thumbnail))
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
           // print(err)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```